# Dropdown not refreshing when i used sumoselect.js plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, sumoselect.js

I use [sumoselect.js](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) plugin and I am trying to get the drop down options dynamically from DB through AJAX. But options are not rebuilding.

I spent couple of hours. Please help me any one on this issue.

Comment: can you add a snippet?

Comment: do you use the **.add()** method?

Comment: This is my code please see below

Comment: $.ajax({
            url: 'url',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'geo=' + $(this).val() ,
            success: function(data) {
                var output = []; 
                $('select#market_search').empty(); 
                $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(key, value)
                {
                    $('select#market_search')[0].sumo.add(value.value);
                }); 
                $('select#market_search').trigger("liszt:updated");

Comment: your code works? can you log the variable **output**?

Comment: when i select value from 1st drop drop 2nd drop should be update with new values. But now old values are adding with new values.

Comment: please, if you can update your question adding js and html fragments of interest in order to get an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

.add() function will work for me and before in for-loop we need to delete previous drop-down values then use .add() function.
I tried its working.

Comment: how are you deleting?
I tried .remove() and .reload(). Nothing works